# Migrate Datastax Enterprise Cassandra to Apache Cassandra or Datastax Community?

Tags: cassandra, migration, datastax

I have a large, but simple Cassandra database on a Datastax 4.6 cluster.  The license renewal is prohibitive for this very simple use case and I am trying to migrate to either a straight Apache or Datastax Comunity version.  First is it possible to do an inline update?

I have altered all the keyspaces to remove the "EverywhereStrategy" replication strategy but I still get an error that the DSC version of cassandra I'm trying to get to join the cluster doesn't support it.  I'm using Like Cassandra versions (2.0.16) and most other things seem to be close.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find replication strategy class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.EverywhereStrategy'`

If it's not possible to do an inline upgrade what would be the best strategy to migrate a decent size (30 node, 150Tb) cluster?

Comment: I had forgot about a lone node in another ring.  I ran the repair on that node and i think it got rid of the last reference to the EverywhereStrategy.  I then had an old test columnfamily with a solr index that was causing issues with the missing classes required for Solr integration.  I dropped that table and now I have been able to join the node to the ring and data seems to be transferring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to make this work you have to extract any of the DSE features that you may have on any of your tables.

This meant I had to change the replication strategy on the dse_system table from EverywhereStrategy to SimpleStrategy with RF=3 (or almost anything after conversion you can drop this keyspace) The error message was:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find replication strategy class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.EverywhereStrategy'`

I Also had to drop the unused CFS keyspaces.  We never used the hadoop/CFS integration so we had nothing in these keyspaces anyway.  I didn't capture the error for this.

We did have a solr index on a table we were testing on this cluster about a year ago so I had to drop this columnfamily.  The error message was:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex`

There may be other incompatibilities if you use other features of Datastax Enterprise that you would have to remove, but this was enough for me to get the migration working.

Answer (score 2):

dse-core.jar contains the EverywhereStrategy class.

We solved this problem by doing the following:

Replace everything except the above JAR so nodes can come up fine. Once all nodes are migrated to OSS, drop the dse_system keyspace (that uses this replication), delete the JAR and restart the nodes one by one.